# Next.js / persisting component between shallow route change

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to change routes whilst persisting the component that triggered the route change.

The expected behaviour should resemble to following:

1. The component is mounted on the source page
2. Once the user clicks on said component, this triggers the following:
3. A route change to the target page
4. A removal of the current page context, including all other mounted components and their state.

`MyComponentToPersist` should persist entirely in it's initial form. No state change or re-render should take place during route change.

##### Source page

```js
// /source-page

const SourcePage = () => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleClick = () => {
    return router.push('/target-page', undefined, { shallow: true })
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SomeOtherComponent />
      <MyComponentToPersist onClick={handleClick} />
      <SomeOtherComponent />
    </>
  )
}
```

##### Target page

```js
// /target-page

const TargetPage = () => {
  return <MyComponentToPersist onClick={handleClick} />
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm I think it's not possible for your case. According to Next.js document (https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing#caveats), Shallow routing only works for URL changes in the current page. If your target page and source page have the same URL (only diff hash or querystring), we can achieve your transition.

Comment: That would be an option. Right now I'm using framer's layoutId (formerly AnimateSharedLayout) to animate between the relative and fixed views. However, this requires two components to be rendered, meaning id have to compute things twice, which is not an option.